# MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

This is my source code :

```
@app.route('/pythonlogin/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    # Output message if something goes wrong...
    msg = ''
    # Check if "username", "password" and "email" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form:
        # Create variables for easy access
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
                # Check if account exists using MySQL
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s", (username))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        # If account exists show error and validation checks
        if account:
            msg = 'Account already exists!'
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
            msg = 'Invalid email address!'
        elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', username):
            msg = 'Username must contain only characters and numbers!'
        elif not username or not password or not email:
            msg = 'Please fill out the form!'
        else:
            # Account doesnt exists and the form data is valid, now insert new account into accounts table
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s)", (username, password, email))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            msg = 'You have successfully registered!'
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        # Form is empty... (no POST data)
        msg = 'Please fill out the form!'
    # Show registration form with message (if any)
    return render_template('register.html', msg=msg)
```

i cant understand why i get this error , my login works fine but my register i have that tiny problem, i run in myswl server  thanks for your time

Comment: Please add your complete error message.

Comment: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting this is my error and this is a screenshot https://prnt.sc/qmb6tk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight issue with your first query.

`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s", (username))`

What this does is unpacks the values passed as the second parameter and places it into your query, usually done with a tuple. Now this seems to be what you intended however there is a minor but very important piece missing here. A tuple with one value **requires** a trailing comma i.e `(username,)` else it is just brackets around your string. Due to this, your string is actually being unpacked and each character is being passed as an argument to your query!

TL;DR

You need to add a trailing comma to your query to pass a tuple, rather than a string as an argument.

`cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s", (username,))`